# My Notification popup shows text color white

Tags: android, text, notifications, popup

My html text color is coming white. Also other text color is white. I don't know why. Please could you help me please ? I research enough on Web.

I dont want to add color to texts.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information. How are you showing this popup? What does your layout file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a theming issue. [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) official guide could be helpful to finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. For me when I would 'expand' my notifications the text would be white and unreadable against the white notification background. I changed my theme as suggested above and the problem went away quick